# identifier "a" is undefined in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing c++ code to implememt universal hash function, but it doesn't recognize the parameters, here is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include "hash.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

HASH::HASH(){
    a=23;
    b=88;
    n=100;
    p=997;
    products=new product[n];
    }  

HASH::~HASH(){
    delete []products;

}  

HASH::HASH(int aa,int bb,int nn, int pp){
    a=aa;
    b=bb;
    n=nn;
    p=pp;
    products=new product[n];

}  


int HF(int key){

    int index;
    int h;

   h=((((a*key)+b)% p)% n);

}
```

in HF function,it tells me that the parameters a,b,n,p are undefined. I defined them in the header file like this:

```
class HASH {
private: 
    int a,b,n,p;
    product* products;

public:

        HASH();
        HASH(int aa,int bb, int nn, int pp);
        ~HASH();
        bool insert(product s);
        bool retrieve(int id,product &product);
        bool updateName(int id);
        bool updateCost(int id);
        bool updateQuantity(int id);
        bool remove(product &d);
        int getNumberOfProducts();

};
int HF(int key);
```

Comment: `HF` isn't a part of the class. It has no knowledge of `a`.

Comment: @chris I moved it inside the class and keep getting same error

Comment: @nos what could be wrong??

Comment: @roa.tah: Did you move the function declaration inside the class, *and* change the name to `HASH::HF` in the definition? If you did all that, then please update your code  so we can see what's still wrong.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thnx, I totally forget to add HASH::HF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, **never** define a variable with a single char, that you will use a lot, or in class. If you wanna find it in code, it will be impossible - you will stop one each "a" char. Name it something readable.

Second, HF is not a **member** of class HASH, it can't see **private** variables of other classes.

1. Add to **public** part of **HASH** class 
   **int HF(int key);**
2. change procedure to
   **int HASH::HF(int key){** ...
   and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Add `int HF` to the public section of your class and in the file `hash.cpp` use `int HASH:HF` instead of `int hash`. 
I noticed a small bug: your function HF doesn't return value  - add return statement to HF function.